# How to calculate Lat,Long,Alt of a pixel in an Image where lat/long/alt corresponding to one of the pixels in the same image is known?

Tags: geometry, geolocation

I have an image taken using a mobile phone like the one attached below. Let's say that I know the location(lat/long/alt) from where this image was taken, which is probably the center of the red circle (lets say pixel x,y), annotated in this image. I want to have any suggestions on how to go about estimating the approximate lat/long/alt coordinates of the annotated traffic signal?

[image]

Comment: Use Google Earth, find your known XY, then locate that traffic pole by comparing imagery.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Dan. However, I want to do that programmatically, by using the geometric projections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you know the look angle (azimuth) of the photo, you can try to estimate 1) how far away the traffic signal is from the known point - maybe 60 feet - and 2) the height difference of the two points - maybe 15 feet - and then just do the trig.

This is known as a [First (direct or forward) geodetic problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#First_(direct_or_forward)_geodetic_problem) and there should be resources out there for that search term.

I imagine it would be easier to **convert your data to a projected coordinate** space so you can use planar math rather than trying to work with geographic coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will explore the resources related to "First (direct or forward) geodetic problem". And I am sorry, I don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer. I will wait for few more suggestions from the community and will mark the best one as accepted.